# Windows Media Player icon view of music disabled

Tags: windows-media-player

Looking at music on the top right of the tool bar in Windows Media Player 11, there are 3 View Options

- Icon
- Expanded Tile
- Detail

Icon is disabled for me.  Why? How can I enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. You have to have it in Album view.  Just by track is not enough.